# ASP.NET C# How to enlarge GridView DataBound imageField picture when hoverover?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am doing school work and need some help, I want the image in a 'Relevant Information' ImageField column that is DataBound to be enlarged when hoverover. Here are my codes:

```
    <div style="height:200px; width: 610px; overflow: auto;">
                <asp:GridView ID="GV_insView" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Width="511px">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Customer ID" DataField="NRIC" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Insurance Type" DataField="insType" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Filed" DataField="dateFiled" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
            <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Relevant Information" DataImageUrlField="relInfo" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100"> 
              </asp:ImageField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write custom JavaScript Function and CSS to support this.

Please find the example code below for how you can do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView1] td").hover(function () {
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("hover_row");
        },function(){
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("hover_row");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the CSS you will use CSS3 property of transform Scale to enlarge on hover.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    td
    {

    }
    .hover_row
    {
        -ms-transform: scale(2, 3); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(2, 3); /* Safari */
         transform: scale(2, 3);
    }
</style>
```

For complete solution you can check this link which is the source of the information above. [Change row color on GridView Hover ASP Snippets](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-change-GridView-Row-Color-on-Mouseover-in-ASPNet.aspx)

For only one boundfield to have some specific CSS you can try this.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="yourclass"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

This way, all boundfields of Image will get that CSS class of hover.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the codes work and I can enlarge the contents in the GridView now. However when I mouse hover over the image, the words in all the other columns are enlarged too. Any way to fix this?

Comment: For only that selected row. What you can do it to put up that CSS property to that  specific boundfield.